# BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity missing, incorrectly configured in AndroidManifest.xml or another app defines the same browser switch url as this app

Tags: java, android, flutter, braintree

I'm trying to implement the Braintree Android SDK into my app. I'm facing a weird error when I try to use the PayPal payment method. The documentation of Braintree says that I have to implement this into my AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so this is my AndroidManifest after implementing:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.plugon.flutterbraintree_example">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutterbraintree_example"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So my code works fine everything is showing up but when I select Paypal for payment I get this error: ***BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity missing, incorrectly configured in AndroidManifest.xml or another app defines the same browser switch url as this app.***

So any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have actually the same problem and I am not able to fix it...

Comment: did you got this @Funkberater

Answer (score 2):

Remove underscores in your package name

"Note: The scheme you define must use all lowercase letters. If your package contains underscores, the underscores should be removed when specifying the scheme in your Android Manifest."

please check this for more information
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2#browser-switch

Comment: This was the problem in my case. this saved my time. Thank you.

Comment: Link no longer works. Just blank screen....

Answer (score 1):

Just remove special characters from your app's package name/id. like underscores and etc.

ex: com.example.smaple_app
solved: ex: com.example.smapleapp

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by renaming my application id. Apparently the braintree SDK does not like to have underscores in the application id. It worked after I renamed the application id to an id without special characters...
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application ID doesn't have any special characters and upper case alphabets. If so please remove the special characters and change the application id to lower case alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in the `application` bloc,  to `AndroidManifest.xml`

and this line

```
<activity android:name="${applicationId}.FlutterBraintreeCustom" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
```